# Send Wired Keyboard Keystrokes Through Bluetooth

Tags: macos, keyboard, bluetooth

I'm looking for a way send keystrokes from a **wired** keyboard through bluetooth, preferably with an OS X application. I want to be able to type things on my iPad using this keyboard so I can quickly switch back and forth between it and my computer. Is there an OS X app that can do this?

Note that I'm running OS X 10.10.3 on a 2010 iMac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## [Type2Phone](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/type2phone/id472717129?mt=12) - $9.99

Any keystrokes you type while Type2Phone is focused will be sent over Bluetooth. You can Command+Tab to and from it as well.